# How to close boostrap Dialog in yii2?

Tags: yii2, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm trying to do this:

1. Open a bootstrap dialog with a button, through a URL. Action of the Url in controller  is `"myController/updateDialog"`.
2. By open dialog, this loads a page (`myController/updateDialog`) with a form to fill data (form has a button to submit).
3. If I submit the form by clicking the button, in my controller I tried close the dialog and refresh some things in the original page, this I do with JS.  But it doesn't work. I always get the window navigator in the blank with the new URL; I expect to keep the original page where the dialog was invoked, to see the changes, same way that does `CJUIDIALOG` in `Yii 1.x`.

The controller's code is:

```
public function actionUpdatedialog($id)
{ 
   $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post() &&  $model->save() )) {           
       $this->view->registerJs("window.close(); window.opener.fn.yiiGridView.update('books-heads'); return false;",
            $this->view::POS_HEAD);//try close and finally 
     die(); //finally 

    } 
    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I tried, with :

`"window.close();"`  and

`"$(#Mymodal).modal('hide');"`  and others, but could not sort it out.

Comment: why are you closing the modal inside the controller action how are you ceting the modal add your view code.

Answer (score 1):

You should submit your form via ajax, accept and determine the return value. If it is successful, call `$("#your modal box").modal('hide')` to close your dialog. e.g:

```
public function actionUpdatedialog($id)
{ 
   $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post() &&  $model->save() )) {           
       \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
       return ['code' => 200, 'message' => 'success'];

    } 
    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

In the page:

```
$("#formName").on('submit', function () {
    // or use ajax
    fetch(...).then(response => {
        response.json().then(json => {
            if (200 === json.code) {
                $("yourModalBox").modal('hide');
            } else {
                alert(json.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer translation from Google Translate, hope this helps you.